# Facing Jacoco Method too large Error when running

Tags: maven, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Facing Method too large Error from jacoco for a method in the drools library, how to resolved this? I also tried adding ****DRL6Lexer.class** to the exlucdes in jacoco but it didn't work. How else can I resolve this issue.

Error:

> java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while
> instrumenting org/drools/compiler/lang/DRL6Lexer.     at
> org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:94)
> at
> java.instrument/java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer.transform(ClassFileTransformer.java:246)
> at
> java.instrument/sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
> at
> java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:563)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)    at
> java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
> at
> org.drools.compiler.compiler.DRLFactory.getDRLLexer(DRLFactory.java:112)
> at
> org.drools.compiler.compiler.DRLFactory.buildLexer(DRLFactory.java:59)
> at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DrlParser.parse(DrlParser.java:163)
> at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DrlParser.parse(DrlParser.java:154)
> at org.drools.compiler.compiler.DrlParser.parse(DrlParser.java:144)
> at DroolsParser.parseDrl(DroolsParser.java:36)  at
> DroolsParserTest.generateRules_success(DroolsParserTest.java:39)  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
> at
> org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
> at
> org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)    at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
> at
> org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)     at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)   at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)  at
> org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)     at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)    at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)    at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.execution.RunnerExecutor.execute(RunnerExecutor.java:40)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
> at
> java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
> at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.executeAllChildren(VintageTestEngine.java:80)
> at
> org.junit.vintage.engine.VintageTestEngine.execute(VintageTestEngine.java:71)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
> at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
> at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting org/drools/compiler/lang/DRL6Lexer.
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:160)
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:110)
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:92)
> ... 64 more
> Caused by: org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.MethodTooLargeException:
> Method too large: org/drools/compiler/lang/DRL6Lexer.mID ()V
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.MethodWriter.computeMethodInfoSize(MethodWriter.java:2087)
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:496)
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:91)
> at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_f3994fa.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:108)
> ... 65 more

pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
          <compilerArgs>
            <compilerArg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</compilerArg>
          </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                    <version>5.4.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-prepare-agent-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>
                            ${project.parent.basedir}/target/site/jacoco/${project.artifactId}
                        </outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-report-integration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-check</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules>
                            <rule>
                                <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                <limits>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>${jacoco.percentage.line}</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>${jacoco.percentage.branch}</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                    <limit>
                                        <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                        <minimum>${jacoco.percentage.complexity}</minimum>
                                    </limit>
                                </limits>
                            </rule>
                        </rules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the Jacoco task extension (an a extension jacoco inject to each task which is of type Test) you can exclude the problematic `DRL6Lexer` class.

for me in gradle this worked.

```
test {
        jacoco{
            excludes = ['org/drools/**/*']
        }
        useJUnitPlatform()
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maven example:

```xml
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org/drools/**/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
...
```

The important part is:

```xml
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>org/drools/**/*</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
```